# How do I play videos on a DLNA projector with my Mac?

Tags: macos, dlna, projector

I have a PicoPro ([manual](http://www.celluon.com/docs/PicoPro_Manual.pdf)) and a Macbook Pro.  I've installed Serviio (I've also tried Universal Media Server, with similar results).  I'm able to get it to connect to/see the projector - but how do I actually play videos?  According to the projector docs:

1. On a desired mobile device, go to WiFi setting, and connect to “Celluon PicoPro”.
   Use password “12345670” to connect.
2. When WiFi is successfully connected, open the installed DLNA streaming application
   on the mobile device.
3. Select desired content to display.
4. Select display location: Celluon PicoPro.
5. Mobile device will say “Connected” and PicoPro will start display selected media contents.

I've completed steps 1 and 2, but how do I select the media to play in Serviio (or UMS)?  It seems like the DLNA device (TV/projector) should have some ability to browse the media, but this projector doesn't. And from those instructions, it seems like there should be some way to "push" the content to the projector, but I have no idea how to do that.